# System Performance Monitoring

Tags: performance

I have been using PAL (Performance analysis tool) to analyse perfmon logs for server performance specific to SharePoint.

Does SharePoint 2010 come with any built-in performance monitoring?  I know the health analyser does some monitoring, but does it cover system resources?

What about SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 has an optional free download called the SharePoint Administration Toolkit. This download includes some performance monitoring in SharePoint Diagnostic Studio.

I don't know about 2007.

Comment: The SharePoint Administration Toolkit isn't available easily at Microsoft anymore. Where can it be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 has web analytics and administrative reports which produces some of this information out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Sam SharePoint Farm Monitoring Tool 1.0

SharePoint Farm Monitoring Tool is to monitor SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 farms and indicate to take action against the objects.

Tool Link:
https://sites.google.com/site/samarendraswain/my-products/sharepointfarmmonitoring

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer in two different questions. This answer is a copy of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148181/monitoring-sharepoint-2010-farm/203502#203502